# How to use Tidyverse to group several columns and calculate percentage and create new df?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I am interested in plotting **Ternary plots**.

How can I use `Tidyverse` to group several columns and calculate the percentage and create new df? I can do this one by one, could not figure out how to use Tidyverse packages.

**Sample data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(AGI = c("ATCG01240", "ATCG01310", "ATMG00070"), aox2_0h__1 = c(15.79105291, 14.82652303, 14.70630068), aox2_0h__2 = c(16.06494674, 14.50610036, 14.52189807), aox2_0h__3 = c(14.64596287, 14.73266459, 13.07143141), aox2_0h__4 = c(15.71713641, 15.15430026, 16.32190068 ), aox2_12h__1 = c(14.99030606, 15.08046949, 15.8317372), aox2_12h__2 = c(15.15569857, 14.98996474, 14.64862254), aox2_12h__3 = c(15.12144791, 14.90111092, 14.59618842), aox2_12h__4 = c(14.25648197, 15.09832061, 14.64442686), aox2_24h__1 = c(15.23997241, 14.80968391, 14.22573239 ), aox2_24h__2 = c(15.57551513, 14.94861669, 15.18808897), aox2_24h__3 = c(15.04928714, 14.83758685, 13.06948037), aox2_24h__4 = c(14.79035385, 14.93873234, 14.70402827), aox5_0h__1 = c(15.8245918, 14.9351844, 14.67678306), aox5_0h__2 = c(15.75108628, 14.85867002, 14.45704948 ), aox5_0h__3 = c(14.36545859, 14.79296855, 14.82177912), aox5_0h__4 = c(14.80626019, 13.43330964, 16.33482718), aox5_12h__1 = c(14.66327372, 15.22571466, 16.17761867), aox5_12h__2 = c(14.58089039, 14.98545497, 14.4331578), aox5_12h__3 = c(14.58091828, 14.86139511, 15.83898617 ), aox5_12h__4 = c(14.48097297, 15.1420725, 13.39369381), aox5_24h__1 = c(15.41855602, 14.9890092, 13.92629626), aox5_24h__2 = c(15.78386057, 15.19372889, 14.63254456), aox5_24h__3 = c(15.55321382, 14.82013321, 15.74324956), aox5_24h__4 = c(14.53085803, 15.12196994, 14.81028556 ), WT_0h__1 = c(14.0535031, 12.45484834, 14.89102226), WT_0h__2 = c(13.64720361, 15.07144643, 14.99836235), WT_0h__3 = c(14.28295759, 13.75283646, 14.98220861), WT_0h__4 = c(14.79637443, 15.1108037, 15.21711524 ), WT_12h__1 = c(15.05711898, 13.33689777, 14.81064042), WT_12h__2 = c(14.83846779, 13.62497318, 14.76356308), WT_12h__3 = c(14.77215863, 14.72814995, 13.0835214), WT_12h__4 = c(14.70685445, 14.98527337, 16.12727292), WT_24h__1 = c(15.43813077, 14.56918572, 14.92146565 ), WT_24h__2 = c(16.05986898, 14.70583866, 15.64566505), WT_24h__3 = c(14.87721853, 13.22461859, 16.34119942), WT_24h__4 = c(14.92822133, 14.74382383, 12.79146694)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**Script I used**

```
    sdf1 <- gather(df1, "group", "Expression",-AGI) %>%
  separate(group, c("sample", "time", "r")) %>%
  unite(tgroup, c("sample", "time"))  %>%
  group_by(AGI, tgroup) %>%
  summarize(expression_mean = mean(Expression)) %>%
  spread(tgroup, expression_mean) %>%
  column_to_rownames(colnames(.)[1])


sdf2 <- mutate(sdf1, WTper_0h = NA, WTper_12h = NA, WTper_24h = NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(sdf2)){
  total_abun <- sum(sdf2$WT_0h[i], sdf2$WT_12h[i], sdf2$WT_24h[i])
  sdf2$WTper_0h[i] <- sdf2$WT_0h[i]/total_abun*100
  sdf2$WTper_12h[i] <- sdf2$WT_12h[i]/total_abun*100
  sdf2$WTper_24h[i] <- sdf2$WT_24h[i]/total_abun*100
}
```

Could someone help me with this

e.g.

% of aox2_oh = [aox2_oh / (aox2_oh+aox2_12h+aox2_24h)] *100

% of WT_12h = [WT_12h / (WT_oh+WT_12h+WT_24h)] *100

Expected outcome.

[image]

Comment: What you mean with several outputs? Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Are the 20, 50 and 30% real data? What is the total_abun for the first sample?

Comment: @patL I mean one by one taking the percentages like above. As my working df is big I want to do this at once.

Comment: @Jimbou  No. I just put to show I want to calculate per that section (total 100)

Comment: What is `df1`? It would be helpful if you could provide `library()` and your code for generating `df1`

Comment: @Zhiqiang Wang I have updated. df= df1

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```r
sdf2 <- df %>%
  gather(variable,value,-AGI) %>%
  group_by(AGI) %>%
  mutate(total_abun = sum(value),perc = 100*value/total_abun)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to know a little better what you mean by calculate the percentage.

This follows along with what you've already done.
But I've interpreted percentage as the mean expression as a percentage of total mean expression for each AGI.

```
sdf2 <- df1 %>%
        pivot_longer(
                cols = c(starts_with('WT_'),
                        starts_with('aox')), 
                names_to = "group", 
                values_to = "expression") %>% 
        separate(group, into = c("sample", "time", "r")) %>% 
        group_by(AGI, sample, time) %>%
        mutate(sample_mean = mean(expression)) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        group_by(AGI, sample) %>%
        mutate(sample_total = sum(sample_mean)) %>%
        unite(tgroup, c("sample", "time")) %>% 
        group_by(AGI, tgroup) %>%
        mutate(expression_pct = sample_mean / sample_total) %>% 
        ungroup() %>%
        select(-sample_total, -r, -expression, -sample_mean) %>%
        distinct() %>%
        pivot_wider(
                names_from = tgroup, 
                values_from = expression_pct) %>% 
        column_to_rownames(var = 'AGI')
```

Comment: for e.g. % of aox2_oh = [aox2_oh / (aox2_oh+aox2_12h+aox2_24h)] *100

Comment: % of WT_12h = [WT_12h / (WT_oh+WT_12h+WT_24h)] *100

Comment: I get an error,  Error in pivot_longer(., cols = c(starts_with("WT_"), starts_with("aox")),  : 
  could not find function "pivot_longer"      > packageVersion("tidyverse")
[1] ‘1.2.1’

Comment: Sorry, 

pivot_longer is only available in the newest version of tidyr. Try reinstalling tidyr and running again. 

How do you want to deal with the 'r' value?

So in the sample data you've provided you get 4 values for each AGI and tgroup.
Getting the sum of WT_* is easy with a group by and mutate. 

So in the updated example, I'm getting the mean for each AGI, sample and time.

So in the following

$WT_12h = [WT_12h / (WT_oh+WT_12h+WT_24h)$

Each value represents the mean the r values at that point.

Comment: Hi tychob_da, Thank you very much. Greatly appreciate. df1 has replicate data for each sample (r), I have averaged them in sdf1.

Comment: for e.g. percentage for WT for "ATCG01240" should be;                    
> 14.19501/(14.19501 + 14.84365 + 15.32586)*100
[1] 31.99631
> 14.84365/(14.19501 + 14.84365 + 15.32586)*100
[1] 33.45838
> 15.32586/(14.19501 + 14.84365 + 15.32586)*100
[1] 34.54531 ,